# Minesweeper implementation in Java

Tags: java, minesweeper

I am nearly complete with my Minesweeper game but the rough idea is done.

My approach is with three classes. One is the tile class which represents a tile on the gameboard. The other is the actual gameboard which is made out of a 2-d array from the tiles. There is no function when you win but wanted to get ideas/ tips from coders.  You can play until you lose.

I have my concerns with the current way I have coded things for example, I am unsure if using `faceUp` is the best way I can represent an unopened tile but for now that is all I could think of. Furthermore, I implemented nearly every possible edge case I could think of for the board.

The main area I would like more help in is checking whether an given coordinate is within bounds.

```
 public class Tile {

    private int numBombsNearBy;
    private String faceUp;
    private boolean isBomb;

    public Tile(){
        numBombsNearBy = 0;
        faceUp = "X";
        isBomb = false;
    }
```

GameBoard class:

```
public class GameBoard {

    /*
    TO DO:
        Create method to show the rest ofthe bombs when the user loses.
     */
    private Tile[][] gameBoard;
    private int xdim = 8;
    private int ydim = 8;
    private List<Pair> listOfBombs = new ArrayList<>();

    public GameBoard(){
        gameBoard = new Tile[xdim][ydim];
        for(int row = 0; row < xdim; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < ydim; col++){
                gameBoard[row][col] = new Tile();
            }
        }
    }

    public Tile[][] getGameBoard(){
        return gameBoard;
    }
    public void gameOver(Tile[][] gameBoard){
        for(int bomb = 0; bomb < listOfBombs.size();bomb++){
            Pair temp = listOfBombs.get(bomb);
            gameBoard[temp.getX()][temp.getY()].setFaceUp("*");
        }
        displaygameBoard();
    }

    public void displaygameBoard(){
        for(int row = 0; row < xdim; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < ydim; col++){
                System.out.print(gameBoard[row][col].getFaceUp() + "|");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public int generateRandomNumber(){

        Random rn = new Random();
        int range = 7 - 0+ 1;
        int randomNum =  rn.nextInt(range) + 0;
        return randomNum;
    }

    public void fillBoardBombs(){
        int row, col = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            row = generateRandomNumber();
            col = generateRandomNumber();
            listOfBombs.add(new Pair(row, col));
            gameBoard[row][col].setBomb(true);
            updateNearByBombs(row, col);
        }
    }

    public boolean checkIfBomb(int x, int y){
        if(gameBoard[x][y].isBomb() == true){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void showTileBomb(int x, int y){
        gameBoard[x][y].setFaceUp(String.valueOf(gameBoard[x][y].getNumBombsNearBy()));
    }




    public void updateNearByBombs(int inputrow, int inputcol){

        //For (0,0)
        if(inputrow == 0 && inputcol == 0){
            for(int row = inputrow; row <= inputrow + 1; row++){
                for(int col = inputcol; col <= inputcol + 1; col++){
                    if(row == inputrow && col == inputcol){
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(0);
                    }else{
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(gameBoard[row][col].getNumBombsNearBy() + 1);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //For (0, (1 - 6))
        else if(inputrow == 0 &&(inputcol >= 1 && inputcol <= 6)){
            for(int row = inputrow; row <= inputrow + 1; row++){
                for(int col = inputcol - 1; col <= inputcol + 1; col++){
                    if(row == inputrow && col == inputcol){
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(0);
                    }else{
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(gameBoard[row][col].getNumBombsNearBy() + 1);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //For (0,7)
        else if(inputrow == 0 && inputcol == 7){
            for(int row = inputrow; row <= inputrow + 1; row++){
                for(int col = inputcol - 1; col <= inputcol;col++){
                    if(row == inputrow && col == inputcol){
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(0);
                    }else{
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(gameBoard[row][col].getNumBombsNearBy() + 1);

                    }
                }
            }
        }


        //For (1 - 6), 0)
        else if((inputrow >= 1 && inputrow <= 6) && inputcol == 0){
            for(int  row = inputrow - 1; row <= inputrow + 1; row++){
                for(int col = inputcol; col <= inputcol + 1; col++){
                    if(row == inputrow && col == inputcol){
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(0);
                    }else{
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(gameBoard[row][col].getNumBombsNearBy() + 1);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //For (7,0)
        else if(inputrow == 7 && inputcol == 0){
            for(int  row = inputrow - 1; row<= inputrow;row++){
                for(int col = inputcol; col <= inputcol + 1;col++){
                    if(row == inputrow && col == inputcol){
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(0);
                    }else{
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(gameBoard[row][col].getNumBombsNearBy() + 1);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //For (7, (1 - 6))
        else if(inputrow == 7 && (inputcol >= 1 && inputcol <= 6)){
            for(int row = inputrow - 1; row <= inputrow; row++){
                for(int col = inputcol - 1; col <= inputcol + 1; col++){
                    if(row == inputrow && col == inputcol){
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(0);
                    }else{
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(gameBoard[row][col].getNumBombsNearBy() + 1);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //For (7,7)
        else if(inputrow == 7 && inputcol == 7){
            for(int row = inputrow - 1; row <= inputrow; row++){
                for(int col = inputcol - 1; col <= inputcol; col++){
                    if(row == inputrow && col == inputcol){
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(0);
                    }else{
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(gameBoard[row][col].getNumBombsNearBy() + 1);

                    }
                }
            }
        }


        //For (1 - 6), 7)
        else if((inputrow >= 1 && inputrow <= 6) && inputcol == 7){
            for(int row = inputrow - 1; row<= inputrow + 1; row++){
                for(int col = inputcol - 1; col <= inputcol;col++){
                    if(row == inputrow && col == inputcol){
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(0);
                    }else{
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(gameBoard[row][col].getNumBombsNearBy() + 1);

                    }
                }
            }
        }


        //for the rest
           else for(int row = inputrow - 1; row <= inputrow + 1; row++){
                for(int col = inputcol - 1; col<= inputcol + 1;col++){
                    if(row == inputrow && col == inputcol) {
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(0);
                    }else{
                        gameBoard[row][col].setNumBombsNearBy(gameBoard[row][col].getNumBombsNearBy() + 1);

                    }
                }
        }

    }

}
```

Main:

```
public class JMineSweeper {

    final static String regex = "^[0-7]\\s+[0-7]$";


    public static String askForUserInput() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String xy = null;
        System.out.print("Enter x and y coordinates seperated by a space: ");
        return xy = input.nextLine();
    }

    public static boolean isCorrectInput(String input){
        if(input.matches(regex)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static List<Integer> convertUserInput(String input){
        String [] splited = input.split("\\s+");
        List<Integer> coordinates =  new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < splited.length; i++){
            coordinates.add(Integer.parseInt(splited[i]));
        }
        return coordinates;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean gameOver = false;
        GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard();
        gameBoard.fillBoardBombs();


        while(!gameOver){
            try{
                gameBoard.displaygameBoard();
                String userInput = askForUserInput();
                if(isCorrectInput(userInput)){
                    List<Integer> coordinates = convertUserInput(userInput);
                    System.out.println(coordinates.toString());
                    if(gameBoard.checkIfBomb(coordinates.get(0), coordinates.get(1))){
                        System.out.println("You lose, tile is a bomb");
                        gameBoard.gameOver(gameBoard.getGameBoard());
                        gameOver = true;
                    }else{
                        gameBoard.showTileBomb(coordinates.get(0), coordinates.get(1));
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Incorrect input");
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the code!

> I have my concerns with the current way I have coded things for example, I am unsure if using `faceUp` is the best way I can represent an unopened tile [...].

No, it isn't.

You already modeled the fields as objects of a class `Tile`. You should go one step further:

There are three types of "Tiles" with different behavior:

1. *bombs* which explode when clicked,
2. *neighbors* of bombs which show how many bombs are around them.
3. *safe* fields without neighboring bombs

In OOP we create new classes when we have differing behavior. So you need to create 3 more classes extending the `Tile` class (which should rather be an interface though...)

Having this you can move some of the logic to the different subclasses of `Tile`.
E.g.: a *safe* field could uncover its neighbors  automatically:

```
class SafeTile{
   private final Collection<Tile> neighbors = new  HashSet<>();
   @Override
   public void addNeighbor(Tile neighbor){ neighbors.add(neighbor);}
   @Override
   public void coverUp(){
     for(Tile neighbor : neighbors)
        neighbors.coverUp();
   }
}
```

> I implemented nearly every possible edge case I could think of for the board.

There is a natural way to deal with that: when the *tiles* know their neighbors you don't need a sophisticated logic to deal with edges and corners. These tiles just have less neighbors...

All you need is a smart way to fill the game board initially. YOu could do like this:

```
class GameBoard{
  private final Tile[][] fields;
  GameBoard(int width, int height, int bombCount){
    fields = new Tile[width][height];
    // deploy bombs
    List<Pair> fieldPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0;i<width;i++)
     for(int j=0; j<height;j++)
       fieldPositions.add(new Pair(i,j));
    List<Pair> bombPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0;i< bombCount;i++)
      bombPositions.add(fieldPositions.remove(new Random().nextInt(fieldPositions.size()));
    for(Pair bombPos : bombPositions){
       fields[bombPos.x][bombPos.y]= new TileBomb();
         // set bomb neigbors, corners and edges not yet handled...
         for(int i =-1; i< 2; i++)
           for(int j =-1; j< 2; j++)
             if(null==fields[bombPos.x+i][bombPos.y+j])
               fields[bombPos.x+i][bombPos.y+j]= new NeighborTile();
    }
    // set safe fields    
    for(int i =0;i<width;i++)
     for(int j=0; j<height;j++)
       if(null==fields[i][j])
         fields[i][j]= new SafeTile();
    // set neigbours   
    for(int i =0;i<width-1;i++)
      for(int j=0; j<height-1;j++){                 
          fields[i][j].addNeigbor(fields[i][j+1]);                 
          fields[i][j].addNeigbor(fields[i+1][j+1]);                 
          fields[i][j].addNeigbor(fields[i+1][j]);  
          fields[i][j+1].addNeigbor(fields[i][j]);                 
          fields[i+1][j+1].addNeigbor(fields[i][j]);                 
          fields[i+1][j].addNeigbor(fields[i][j]);       
       }
  }
}
```

The advantage is that you do not need handle field positions during runtime anymore. Just select a field and tell it that it has been uncovered.

---

> Why in the if statement for setting neighbor bombs is there `if(null == field...)`.

Initially there are no objects in the `field` array, any field refers to `null`.

After placing a new bomb (b) we want to place all neighbor fields with new objects:

```
 - - -      n n n
 - b -  ->  n b n
 - - -      n n n
```

The two inner loops iterate the sequence `-1`, `0`, `1`. This means we get all 9 possible combinations. But at `x+0 - y+0` is the bomb object we don't want to overwrite. 
We could have checked for `k` and `l` not being both `0` which would have worked for the current bomb position. But what if we have  placed another bomb (B) in a  field nearby in some previous iteration?

```
 N N N -
 N B N -
 N N b -
 - - - -
```

By checking the possible neighbor field for being empty (referencing to `null`) we do not need a sophisticated logic to avoid replacing the actual or any previously placed bomb with a *neighbor* object by accident.  We also don't replace any already placed *neighbor* field (except with a *bomb*) but that is less important.

On the other hand a new bomb can (and should) replace a previously placed *neighbor*. Therefore we do not check when placing a *bomb*.

---

> why does a safe tile need to know tis neighbors

A `SafeTile` is a field without a bomb in any of its neighbor fields. By the rules of "mine sweeper" all connected *safe* and *neighbor* fields are uncovered when a *safe* field is hit.

By having the `SafeTile` knowing its neighbors <sub>(which are either of class `SafeTile` too or of class `NeighborTile`, but never *bombs*)</sub> the current `SafeTile` can call the `coverUp()` method on its neigbors. Any neighbor which is a `SafeTile` itself will also propagate the call to its neighbors recursively, causing a *chain reaction*. 
<sup>keep in mind that my quick shot  causes an *infinite loop*...</sup>

> and what would be the meaning of cover up?

The method `coverUp()` is meant to be called by the *User Interface* (UI) to trigger the state change from "unknown" to "visited". Obviously the subclasses of `Tile` will behave differently when this method is called on them.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Timothy! I am going over the code to see how I can implement it but before I do, I have a question. Why in the if statement for setting neighbor bombs is there if(null == field...).  I have not seen this before and wanted to get an understanding of it.

Comment: @TheLearner *"Why in the if statement for setting neighbor bombs is there `if(null == field...)`. "* - Answer updated.

Comment: Awesome explanation! One more question if I may. Within the set safe fields code block, why do we make all other tiles Neighbor tiles?

Comment: @TheLearner *"Within the set safe fields code block, why do we make all other tiles Neighbor tiles?"* - because I did not correct it after *copy/paste* (but now...) ;o)

Comment: Actually I have one more question why does a safe tile need to know tis neighbors and what would be the meaning of cover up?, Thank you for your feedback this is helping me! I am going to make these improvements within my code thank you Timothy!

Comment: `coverUp` seems like a weird name choice. Perhaps `uncover` would make the intent clearer?

Comment: @yuri I'm a big fan of changing identifier names to be as expressive as possible, but in this answer other issues have higher priority...